# Assessing the unavoidability of a set kof structures?

Tags: reference-request

Consider a family of structures equipped with a "sub-structure" relation - e.g. subwords, subpermutations or induced subgraphs. Given a set of structures $\cal{K}$, we denote by $Av(\cal{K})$ the family of structures $S$ that do not contain any element of $\cal{K}$ as a sub-structure. We say that $\cal{K}$ is *unavoidable* if $Av(\cal{K})$ is finite, i.e. every sufficiently large structure contains an element of $\cal{K}$.

I'm not knowledgeable on this subject but it seems to have interesting aspects. In particular I'm interested in the following problem: given a set $\cal{K}$, what is the complexity of deciding if $\cal{K}$ is unavoidable? Without a single glance at the literature I'm pretty sure that this is easy for words, but the kinds of objects I'm interested in seem to lie at the border (mainly permutations / languages / trees) and it's not clear to me on what side they fall ($\sf{P}$ or $\sf{NP}$-hard).